# Move the cell in jupyter notebook up and down

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a cell (cell 39), I wish to move up to the top of cell 40.
I know I could grab and drag to the place. However, I see that in [official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_move-a-code-cell), you could move it with the vertical bar on the left. However, I does not have one, and could not find the setting to make it display.

[Demonstration in Visual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KJeg.png).

Jupyter Notebook in chrome version has a similar botton for this function
[Jupyter Notebook web version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkQvr.png).

Comment: the demo you show is working with the vscode native notebook api [checkhere](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/notebook), and the official document is still using the jupyter api.

Answer (score 25):

According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6812 you can use alt(option)+arrow up/down to move the selected cell.

Or, use Command Palette with `Notebook: Move`

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30305945/127107696-af3caf2a-1757-44d0-a619-ae4e82c03037.png]

Comment: Golly. I looked for something in the menu of options for, like, a whole quarter of an hour before deciding to Google it. Thanks!

Comment: Weird the indicated shortcut Alt+UpArrow aren't working?

Comment: After playing around, I figured out how to make the keyboard shortcut work.  You need to click the left margin of the cell (right below the play button) like you're going to drag the cell with the mouse.  Once the cell is not highlighted (blue border around cell) but the vertical blue line is still there, you can then use the keyboard command to move the cell up/down.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, keyboard shortcut (`Alt`+Arrow) didn't work for me. I dragged it with the Mouse pointer.

On the left side, beside the play button, click the grey bar, which will turn into Blue. Then drag it with you mouse wherever you want to place it. Or you directly click the grey bar and drag it. (Shown in the GIF)

[image]